# QtDataVisualization applications with QML and C++ back-end - is it possible?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm developing applications to display very large lidar/sonar datasets (millions of points). QML/Qt seems an attractive platform, since in theory one can quickly define the UI with QML, and implement the "back-end" with high-performance C++. The QtDataVisualization package also seems very useful, especially the Surface3D and Surface3DSeries components for my application. But the provided examples either demonstrate a pure QML approach - which is impractical for my application, with millions of points - or a pure C++ ("widget") approach - which loses the benefit of quickly designing the UI with QML and is locked to a desktop computing platform.

Can someone point to a working example showing how to set QML Surface3DSeries data from C++? This seems theoretically possible from the documentation, but I have been unable to do it, and none of the provided examples demonstrate it. Is this even possible, or is Qml/Qt "broken" in this regard?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is possible, but not officially supported and not documented.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/113498/how-to-use-qt-s-declarativesurface-in-my-app)